# Standard ashx files will not compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, ashx

WebSite / .net framework 4.6.1 / VS2017

If I rightclick project/Add/Add New Item/Visual c#/ Generic Handler
and click add then VS2017 creates an .ashx file. That file will compile and runs ok but the editor view gives errors in the error list window.

Cleaned solution and rebuild => no change

Cleaned solution and restarted vs2017 and rebuild => no change

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

I expected it to give no errors but it gave:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   1   Active
Error   CS1646  Keyword, identifier, or string expected after verbatim specifier: @ Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   1   Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   1   Active
Error   CS0116  A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods   Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   1   Active
Error   CS1022  Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected   Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   1   Active
Error   CS1529  A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations    Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   2   Active
Error   CS1529  A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations    Miscellaneous Files C:\Users\xxx\Handler.ashx   3   Active
```

Comment: Are you sure that is your **exact** code? Where is your namespace declaration?

Comment: That's exactly what vs2017 makes; no namespace. Adding a namespace does not make a difference though.